# new WC_Order(); Coming Back Empty

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to use `new WC_Order( $order_id );` to pull in info from orders to send to an API and the call comes back empty.

I have also tried using `wc_get_order( $order_id );` and I have confirmed that the `$order_id` is valid and returning what I would expect. I also looked around and can't find any input into why this call is coming back empty. Any ideas would be welcome!

Relevant code starts around line 300.

```
public function process_order($order_id) {
    // if ( !$this->api_ready() ) return false;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    update_post_meta($order_id, 'woo_pd_order_orderid', $order);
```

link to repo: https://github.com/deganhart/Printdropper-for-WooCommerce/blob/master/printdropper-for-woocommerce.php#L303

Comment: `wc_get_order()` is the new `new WC_Order()`. but your problem might be, that woocommerce isn't even initiated?